# Remote desktop for multiple music students

Tags: networking, active-directory

I run a community music project for disadvantaged children in West Dunbartonshire and would like to know if there is any way to enable participating children to access their learning materials (in the form of sibelius files) remotely without having to download the software. Using the loop and play back features within the scores would be a great help to them when practicing and for tutors also during zoom lessons.

All suggestions greatly appreciated as we have some digital confidence funding from the heritage lottery and could potentially set up as a server to make the software more widely available depending on any necessary licensing agreements I suppose.

[www.gael.org.uk](http://www.gael.org.uk)

Comment: I will leave comments on technical solutions to better qualified people, but if I were you I would check the licensing conditions of Sibelius in such an environment. Good luck!

Comment: You may want to remove your email address, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

RDP can transmit sound even in both directions. You can try to create Remote Desktop connections for your students, possibly with RemoteApp, so they will only see just one application, Sibelius, and no remote desktop itself.

You'll need to ensure Sibelius is able to run in such environment and you have all necessary software licenses. Test a stability! This way certainly will have some delay, and it is possibly unpredictable, so for example "local metronome with remote accompanying" will be impossible.